# Multilingual App Toolkit Support for VS2022

Tags: visual-studio, localization, visual-studio-extensions

The ["Multilingual App Toolkit"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MultilingualAppToolkit.MultilingualAppToolkit-18308&ssr=false#qna) is not available in the Extension Manager for Visual Studio 2022 (yet). How can I build a project/solution that depends on this extension with VS2022? Without this support, I can't upgrade to .NET6.0 either, because that is no longer compatible with VS2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a workaround for this problem when VS2019 is installed together with the Multilingual App Toolkit for that version.

Simply copy the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Multilingual App Toolkit` to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Msbuild\Microsoft\Multilingual App Toolkit`. After this, VS2022 happily compiles projects depending on this extension.

Answer (score 2):

Multilingual App Toolkit for VS 2022 has been released:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dts-publisher.mat2022